# Arch PC freezes when third screen connects

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, hdmi, asus

I have a very strange issue with my Arch Linux install.

When a HDMI cable is connected to my graphic card (a GTX 970), my PC won't boot, it only shows a black screen, but it will start if the HDMI cable is disconnected.

If I plug in the HDMI cable while Arch runs, the PC freezes.

I have the same issue if I use the DVI-D port.

At this time I'm using Display Port and DVI-A do not have this problem.

How may I approach this? Which logs would be useful?

EDIT : 
I later found this happens when i plug a third screen using any connector.
Another strange detail, 3 screens are working only if i plug the third one (DVI-A) during the boot; if I plug it before, it won't start, and if I plug it in  after boot, the PC freezes.

EDIT 2:
Thank you for your answer ! This is not a laptop but a tower i build myself with:

- Nvidia [GTX970 ASUS STRIX](https://www.asus.com/us/Graphics-Cards/STRIXGTX970DC2OC4GD5/) (driver : nvidia 415.27-5 )
- Intel i5 4590K (xf86-video-intel not installed)
- Motherboard [H81M-PLUS](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/H81MPLUS/specifications/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from GDM, so I move the custom config and re-install it with :

```
sudo systemctl disable gdm
sudo pacman -R gdm
sudo pacman -S gdm
sudo mv /etc/gdm/custom.conf /etc/gdm/custom.conf.old
sudo systemctl enable gdm
```